# What does >> mean in PHP?

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

Consider:

```
echo 50 >> 4;
```

Output:

```
3
```

Why does it output 3?

Comment: This applies to any language with bitwise operations.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

50 in binary is `11 0010`, shift right by 4 yields `11` which is equal to 3.

See [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts).

Comment: Bitwise operator. Specifically, arithmetic shift right bitwise operator.

Comment: Since you are dealing with PHP, you may look at additional information about it here (http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php). The wiki page is also relevant (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts)

Comment: somewhat related? [c++ doc on bitwise operators](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/38-bitwise-operators/)

Answer (score 22):

As documented on [php.org](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php), the `>>` operator is a bitwise shift operator which shifts bits to the right:

> $a >> $b - Shift the bits of $a $b steps to the right (each step means "divide by two")

50 in binary is `110010`, and the `>>` operator shifts those bits over 4 places in your example code. Although this happens in a single operation, **you could think of it** in multiple steps like this:

- Step 1 - `00011001`
- Step 2 - `00001100`
- Step 3 - `00000110`
- Step 4 - `00000011`

Since binary `11` is equal to `3` in decimal, the code outputs 3.

Comment: You may want to right-pad those with 0s to make it more clear (while technically the same, it looks like the bits are not shifting, but rather dropping from the right side).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - just I updated the answer to clarify both points.

Comment: +1 , Best explanation for someone who has never explored bitwise operations.

Answer (score 3):

>> is the binary right-shift operator.

Your statement shifts the bits in the numeric value 50 four places to the right. Because all integers are represented in [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement), this equals 3. An easy way to remember this is that one shift to the right is the same as dividing by 2, and one shift to the left is the same as multiplying by 2.

Answer (score 3):

The `>>` operator is called a *[binary right shift](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)* operator.

Shifting bits to the right 4 times is the same as dividing by two, four times in a row. The result, in this case would be `3.125`. Since 50 is an int, bit shifting will return the floor of this, which is `3`.

Put another way, `50` is `0b110010` in binary. Shifted 4 times we have `0b11`, which is `3` in decimal.

Answer (score 3):

[Arithmetic shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) right.

Answer (score 1):

It shifts the bits down four places.

50 in binary is 110010.

Shifted down four places is 11, which is 3.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a right shift.
'The bits of the left operand are shifted right by the number of positions of the right operand.  The bit positions vacated on the left are filled with the sign bit, and bits shifted out on the right are discarded.'

Information can be found on it here:
http://php.comsci.us/etymology/operator/rightshift.php

Comment: The link is broken (*"This domain name has expired."*).

Answer (score 1):

For your convenience, one of the fastest ways to calculate the outputted value from a bitwise shift is to multiply or divide by 2.

For example `echo 50 >> 4;`

Given that this is a bitwise right, it literally means that the value will be decrease, then we can get the output by divide 50 for 2 and 4 times.

`echo 50 >> 4;` // 50/(2*2*2*2) ~ 3.

Given that (from) 48 -> (to) 63/16(2*2*2*2), the result will be more than 2 and less than 4. Then

`echo 48 >> 4;` // 48/(2*2*2*2) ~ 3.

`echo 63 >> 4;` // 63/(2*2*2*2) ~ 3.

**However, when bitwise left, the result will be totally different as it multiplies by 2 with n times:**

If `echo 50 << 4;` // 50*(2*2*2*2) ~ 800

If `echo 51 << 4;` // 51*(2*2*2*2) ~ 816

Live example: https://3v4l.org/1hbJe